# How to use app.method() to do authorization

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authorization, saas

I am trying to use express then `next('route')` but I am not finding much in the docs on how to do this, it is mentioned [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application). But it doesn't explain how to do the

> will work only in middleware functions that were loaded by using the app.METHOD() or router.METHOD() functions.

I don't get what they mean by that because I have never used `app.METHOD()` before and again am unable to find docs on how to do it properly with the `next('route')`. Would this work?

```
app.method('*', (req, res, next) => {
 if(req.user == null) {
   next();
 } else {
   User.findOne({"_id": req.user.id}, function(err, result) {
    if(err){
     console.log(err);
    } else {
     if(stripe.active == false && stripe.trial == false){
      res.render('/dashboard/billing');
      next('route');
    } else {
      next();
    }
   }
  });
 } 
});
```

Would that even work? I am guessing somewhere in there I messed up something. If I did that right then it would find a user, then check is both `is_active` and `is_trial` are false and if so skip onto the next route. The idea of me doing this is so that a use can any part of the site that doesn't have a logged in user then when there is a logged in user and both are false I only let them go to `/dashboard/billing`. This was suggested to me as a way to prevent users who have not paid yet their trial is over from accessing my application.

Route I am testing on:

```
// dashboard
 app.get('/dashboard',
 setRender('dashboard/index'),
 setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
 isAuthenticated,
 (req, res, next) => {      

 },
 dashboard.getDefault);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, change the method to the right HTTP method request. In the documentation, it specifies what .METHOD() represents:

> app.METHOD() functions, where METHOD is the HTTP method of the request
>   that the middleware function handles (such as GET, PUT, or POST) in
>   lowercase.

In other words, .METHOD() is a place holder for .get, .post, .put, etc.

Try changing that in your app:

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
 if(req.user == null) {
   next();
 } else {
   User.findOne({"_id": req.user.id}, function(err, result) {
    if(err){
     console.log(err);
    } else {
     if(stripe.active == false && stripe.trial == false){
      res.render('/dashboard/billing');
      next('route');
    } else {
      next();
    }
   }
  });
 } 
});
```

See if you can work it out from there.

**Update**

Calling .next('route') right after res.render() cancels res.render() because .next('route') will send the request to the next router.

Comment: I took it too literal... damm. Does the rest of it look decent? I am trying to get it to work but the issue I am having is that while my pages all load, I can't change the variables in the user profile to false. Well at least I don't know how to do it manually.

Comment: I figured out I can change the `&&` to `||` to test but it still seems to let me through to the pages I don't want it to.

Comment: You want to send the user to next router if stripe.active == false || stripe.trial == false ?

Comment: For test yes, since both won't be false until 14 days is up and I don't want to wait that long. I figure if the or works the and should too. Then I can come back to this in 14 days when both will be false to make sure it worked and if not fix it then when I have an account that will be what I need to test with.

Comment: Could you specify which pages you want to let the user access and which not ? Also "*" will accept any request is that right ? I posted a small update.

Comment: Yes `*` should accept any, I want it to be for the `/dashboard` routes only but having it run on all is fine I guess

Comment: I saw your update, I tried removing it and it still goes to the right page and won't go to `/dashboard/billing`

Comment: I would try console logging stripe.active and stripe.trial to see that I'm getting the right values. Try adding several console logs to see that you are getting the expected values.

Comment: I have done that, I am getting it to show correct values compared to when I check my database using a test page. I am having it get to the last else. I can't get it to resolve the `if` compare correctly. None the less I will figure that one out. When I put `10 == 10` to get the if to be truthy, I get can't send headers. I added the route to the OP. EDIT I changed the if statment and it works correct now but still get the can't send headers twice

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more code, do you have a repo or something ?

Comment: I do not have a public repo for this. I did use this boilerplate which is where most of the odd code comes from. [here](https://github.com/eddywashere/node-stripe-membership-saas)

Comment: When the code from the `*` calls the `next('route')` what exactly happens? I thought it would just skip the rest of the code and allow me to render or redirect a user somewhere before hand.

Comment: next('route') means that the next router will take care, You can have several routers declared separately one after another.

Comment: So using the route from my OP could you explain what happens? I am confused. So it would then go to say `app.get('/' foo bar` instead of going to the callback or middleware I have? Like what order is this called in compared to middleware? That might be my issue.